# Parsing JSON with identical keys in object

Tags: android, retrofit

One of the responses from the New York Times API come in the form of JSON like this.

```
 "multimedia":" ",
 "multimedia":[ { array of objects } ]
```

These two name-value pairs are in the same JSON object. I am using Retrofit to take this response into a POJO object. As you can imagine I am having problems doing that since there are two values with the same name. How do I obtain the multimedia that I want?

Comment: I know it's valid to have duplicate identical keys in json object but why do you want to do that? I don't think it's a good approach

Comment: I didnt write the JSON. Its a response from the New York Times API.

Comment: which query gives you that?

Comment: http://developer.nytimes.com/io-docs  Select NewsWire API, then click the recent news function. Put "world" as the section you want then click "Try" to get the response with the JSON I am having the problem with.

Comment: On a another look it seems that articles with no multimedia have value " ", while articles with multimedia have an array value.